# Quick way to create multi-array with same size of another without iterating?

Tags: java, arrays

Just a quick question is there a quick method of creating a new multi-array with the same as another without iterating through each of the first arrays (as it could be a jagged array).

I haven't found such a solution yet so wondering if it exists or not. Just wondering if Java already has a handy efficient way of doing so?

Example if I wasn't clear:

```
int[][] array1 = new int[5][4];
int[][] array2 = // quickly (one line) make this the same as above based on array1 without iterating through each first array?
```

Just to clarify, I don't care about the contents, just the size.

Answer (score 2):

You can try:

```
int[][] array2 = new int[array1.length][array1[0].length];
```

assuming that your array will always be square and that you don't have dimensions of 0.

Comment: For the question example of [5][4], I thought this would create [4][5]

Comment: @anonymous Yes, I had the dimensions flipped; thanks!

Comment: Yeah I thought about that originally with the assumption that it will always be a square, which although I have been told should, I shouldn't rely fully on it... If only Java kept track of the length of the largest inner array, then I wouldn't mind a lit bit of wasted space if it was jagged.

Answer (score 0):

you can try [java.util.Arrays#copyOf](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html)

Comment: See the last sentence of the question.

Comment: @arshajii So then it doesn't matter that they are the same :)